# Remove directory in htaccess with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to strip down

```
http://host.name/html/about.html
```

to

```
http://host.name/about.html
```

But I keep encountering a 404 error with the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritebase /
RewriteRule ^html/(.*) $1 [R,L]
```

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ says its valid, and i think its valid, but there is clearly something I missed.

Can anyone correct me?

Edit:

It also bounces to root when I try to visit /html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it backwards. Since the actual resource is at `/html/about.html`, you need to internally rewrite **to** that URI, not from. Once the internal rewrite is in place, you can externally redirect any direct requests to the `html` directory. So something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /html
RewriteRule ^html/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/html%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/html%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/html%{REQUEST_URI} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /html/$1 [L]
```

Or you could replace the last set of conditions/rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/html/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /html/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope, same outcome. Direct access to /html bounces back to root but specific pages 404's